# Bold only a part of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

Im displaying a message on a webpage in this format "5 pencils will be given to 6 students".

```
"span style="" data-bind="text: app.summary()"/span"
```

Knock out databind is used here. `summary()` is a js method which returns me this message in the format defined in `message.js` file as `"{0} pencils will be given to {1} students"`
but i need to display only the numbers as bold in the final HTML page.

I.e.**5** pencils will be given to **6** students.
I don't want to create individual span and split the string message.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
"<strong>{0}</strong> pencils will be given to <strong>{1}</strong> students"
```

Comment: This is ugly, but this is the only way without using HTML or Javascript to split the string in different parts. But it's very ugly to mix content and style :S